# check a particular hotfix for wmencoder is installed or not

Tags: c#

i want to check a particular hotfix is installed or not for wmencoder in windows 2000.where do i look at the registry or is there someotherway to find it

i already looked into that, for xp entries are there ,but for windows 2000 nothing is
there

is ther anyway for doing this

Answer (score 1):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815340/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-updates-and-hotfixes) (How do I get a list of installed updates and hotfixes)

Using WMI and [Win32_QuickFixEngineering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394391(VS.85).aspx) you can get all the hotfixes that are installed on the system.

```
const string query = "SELECT HotFixID FROM Win32_QuickFixEngineering";
var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
var collection = search.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject quickFix in collection)
    Console.WriteLine(quickFix["HotFixID"].ToString());
```