# List of Installed Updates on Windows 7 C#

Tags: c#, registry, wmi

With Microsoft Ultimate Wisdom they have changed the location of updates from Registry. I can get the updates from Windows 2003 Servers no problem. Its just that Windows 7 is no longer in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Any body got any other ways to get it. Preferably in C# or using WMI?

God Save Microsoft with their Wisdom

Comment: May i ask the reason for a close.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815340/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-updates-and-hotfixes. Or are you asking about Windows 7-specific registry key?

Comment: Thanks Helen that would do nicely :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Window 7 64-bit it's in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates

Comment: It half works... i have Visual Studio updates but thats it :(

Answer (score 0):

```
private string GetX64Installedsoftware()
{
    string Software = null;
    string SoftwareKey = @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

    Software += "\r\nWINDOWS X64 Software\r\n\r\n\r\n ";
    using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SoftwareKey))
    {
        if (rk == null)
        {
            return Software;
        }
        foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!(sk.GetValue("DisplayName") == null))
                    {
                        if (sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") == null)
                            Software += sk.GetValue("DisplayName") + " - Install path not known \r\n ";
                        else
                            Software += sk.GetValue("DisplayName") + " - " + sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") + "\r\n ";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Software;
}
```