# C# code to find all office updates installed

Tags: c#, windows, windows-installer, ms-office, wmi

In add or remove programs you can view list of updates/patches for MS office Outlook. Is there a way to get this information using c# code. We tried WMI code

```
const string query = "SELECT HotFixID FROM Win32_QuickFixEngineering";
var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
var collection = search.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject quickFix in collection)
    Console.WriteLine(quickFix["HotFixID"].ToString());
```

This only lists windows updates. Is there a way to list updates for office components?(for windows XP)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will have to use the registry to get these. The following registry keys should help:

> @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
>   @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

You will have to loop though both the values for the **HKLM** and **HKCU** hives in order to be sure you have everything. Then you can filter on **DisplayName** and **Publisher** for each entry in order to get only the MS office patches.

**Note** you could also try to query the [Win32_Product](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class to get products installed by the Windows installer. Although I have often found that it does not list everything you need (however it might be sufficient for your current problem - but I am not in a position to check right now).

Comment: The registry entries listed above does not include every item listed in the add or remove programs. The solution suggested is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815340/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-updates-and-hotfixes