# Is COM Wrapper generated by tlbimp is OS version dependent

Tags: windows, com, interop, com-interop, tlbimp

We are generating Interop dll for wuapi.dll using tlbimp.exe. Is this interop dll genrated by tlbimp.exe dependent on OS version?

Are there any dependencies on wuapi.dll that has to be packaged if this has to packaged and installed on client machines?

For more context :

[C# code to find all office updates installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529719/c-code-to-find-all-office-updates-installed)

[How do I get a list of installed updates and hotfixes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815340/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-updates-and-hotfixes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wuapi.dll has an OS dependency so the interop library does as well.  Judging from the interface names there may be 6 versions of it out there.  I see IUpdate through IUpdate5 for example on Win7.  Trying to use a newer interface is liable to fail if you're running on an old version of Windows.  Which interface is available on what version of Windows isn't documented in the MSDN library articles, you'll have to test this yourself.  You can get old versions of Windows through an MSDN subscription.

Nothing but the interop library should be deployed, this is an operating system component.