# When does Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable lead to PC reboot

Tags: visual-c++, windows-installer, vcredist

In some machines installing Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable requires PC reboot. However, if we
1)Install Redistributable
2)Reboot
3) Remove Redistributable
4) Try to install it again
It doesn't require a reboot on the second attempt of installation. In addition, in some cases it doesn't require reboot even on the first attempt to install it. It looks that it depends not on Redistributable itself but on some KB update or something like that.
It's pretty important for me to reproduce the "reboot required" environment for Installer debugging purposes. Maybe someone knows how it works and how I can reproduce "reboot required" situations.

Comment: The installation would require a reboot if the UCRT was installed or updated. Or if a running process had the runtime loaded. Or... it's anybody's guess, you'd have to decompile the setup package for that.

Comment: We have also faced this and this asks for restart even by using `/norestart`

Comment: [Please check this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52758087/129130). Not that much to go on, but maybe it is a start. Note that to extract a setup.exe bundle using dark.exe you need to install [the WiX toolkit](https://wixtoolset.org/releases/). The content of the setup.exe might be different by now. [The latest supported Visual C++ downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Comment: Did you manager to find out the reason?