# How to check the update version of IE8

Tags: c#, c++, windows, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp-sp3

I can get IE8 version from registry which is 8.0.6001.18702

and we need to install an cumulative security update (Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer 8 for Windows XP (KB2925418))

Some of our features relies on this update, so this update or later version of update should be fine for us.

I check the version of IE8, it keeps same.

May I know how can we check if a update or later update is installed or not, is there anything like update version in the registry we can use?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the documentation [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2925418), it doesn't look like this patch updates any of the IE8 files; instead it's updating operating system components that IE8 uses.

Since it's updating the operating system, you have two options:

1. You can check the the version of the files that are being updated.  Assuming that it is Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 (the most likely candidates if you're dealing with IE8), then [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824994) article lists the files that you need to check (half-way down the page).
2. If you're looking for this update **specifically** you can query Windows for the list of patches and hotfixes that have been installed.  You can find out out to do that in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815340/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-updates-and-hotfixes) Stack Overflow question.