# Is there any Windows API to show "Installed Updates"

Tags: java, winapi

Is there any Windows API available to show the list of patches under Control Panel >> Programs >> Programs and Features >> Installed Updates, that I can use in a Java program

Comment: You're going to be pretty hard pressed to access such information from java, which is meant to be platform independent. There are a few libraries taking advantage of JNI that can access widnows native APIs but finding an API that implements such a specific functionality for windows makes me think there's unlikely to be an out of box solution

Comment: Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387287(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I'm afraid that [questions looking for offsite resources, such as libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @BenSteffan: Asking specifically about the Windows API is not the same asking to recommend a library. This question is not off-topic for that reason.

Comment: @IInspectable As far as I understand the question, it is not about **the** Windows API, but about **any** API for Windows that does what is requested, not necessarily from official sources. However, that might just be my misinterpretation.

Comment: @BenSteffan: *"Is there any Windows API available"* leaves very little room for interpretation. This is about the Windows API. The tag [tag:winapi] is a pretty strong indication, too.

Comment: The task that has been given to me to is to write a program to list the patches in "Installed Updates" and write the out in an xml file under a predefined location. I tried to use "powershell.exe gwmi Win32_QuickFixEngineering" in my java program but it is giving in-complete list.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh Since you mentioned that *PowerShell* isn't necessarily off limits, see the last answer here: [How do I get a list of installed updates and hotfixes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815340/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-updates-and-hotfixes)